# systemd service start after time synced and server online

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

I made a system service for a python script, I want it starts on boot after the server is online and the time is synced correctly.

What do I have to add in .service file?

I tried in [Unit] with

```
After=network-online.target time-sync.target
```

but it didn't work, it starts with time in January 1970 and not on Internet.

How can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you hit [this systemd issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5097). It fixed in v239. Check your systemd version, if it not v239, you could try workaround from git issue.

Comment: systemd 219
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN

Comment: I should update, but it's a Pine A64, like a Raspberry, Arm64 on CentOS

Comment: @IgorZ.have you tried this workaround - https://git.lukeshu.com/systemd-timesyncd-wait/